# Extracting a large layer from NetCDF using R

Tags: r, netcdf

i am trying to extract specific data from an .nc file

my nc file has the following variables
   hur-relative humidity
   lat-latitudes
   lon-longitudes
   time-time 
   plev-pressure levels

so i want to get the data of relative humidity for a specific plev and specific time

```
library(ncdf)
ncin<-open.ncdf("akhil.nc")
hur.array<-get.var.ncdf(ncin,"hur")
 error: cannot allocate 2.1 gb vector
```

as you can see the hur is to big so is there  any way to directly specify the plev values and time values directly into the 
get.var.ncdf() function so has to reduce the vector size

i am new to ncdf files

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions in the raster package to avoid this problem

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("akhil.nc", var="hur")
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Read the help on the get.var.ncdf(nc, varid=NA, start=NA, count=NA, verbose=FALSE, signedbyte=TRUE, forcevarid=NA) function with:

```
?get.var.ncdf
```

and use the start=c(1,3,5,7,1...), count=c(1,1,1,1,-1,....) parameters  appropriate to your dataset.